# Mac OSX audio output effect

Tags: macos, audio

It seems that almost every Windows audio driver has this feature: **echo** effects on the system output.

What is there on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 0):

Those effects are provided by your audio card driver. They modify the input audio, apply the effect and output the result. OSX audio drivers do not include any such effects. You will have to use another software that provides such effect and play your audio files through it.

Answer (score -1):

You could use [Soundflower](http://cycling74.com/products/soundflower/) to route system audio to something like AU Lab included with Apple Developer Tools at `/Developer/Applications/Audio/` (or GarageBand, I suppose), apply an echo or reverb effect there, and output that to the system audio interface.

Comment: See [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/321634/os-x-filter-system-audio-out-to-remove-high-pitched-noise/321791#321791) for more detailed instructions for using Soundflower with AULab or GarageBand.