# OS X: Filter system audio-out to remove high-pitched noise?

Tags: macos, audio

I am watching a long video on YouTube and the audio is terrible, mostly because there is a lot of high-frequency noise. I'm about to get a headache.

Is there any software that can capture my system audio out (like Airfoil can) and run it through filters, or even a simple multi-band equalizer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Set [Soundflower](https://rogueamoeba.com/freebies/soundflower/) as the default output device (in order to capture output from applications that don't support custom output devices)
- In the application that's used for the effects, set the input device to Soundflower and the output device to a normal output

---

The default output device can be changed from the Sound preference pane or Audio MIDI Setup:

[image]

---

The application that's used for the effects needs to support:

- Custom input and output devices ([Fission](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/fission/) doesn't?)
- Playthru with effects ([Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) doesn't?)

I added instructions for Garage Band and AU Lab, but any DAW or standalone version of an effect plugin would probably do as well.

---

Garage Band only allows you to make a new project by choosing a template. Anyway choose for example the Voice template:

[image]

Change the input and output devices in the preferences:

[image]

Focus an audio track, and enable playing back the input:

[image]

Add effects in the edit tab:

[image]

---

AU Lab was installed with Xcode before 4.3, but it can now be downloaded from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/.

[image]
[image]

Comment: My hero. Thank you for the clear instructions for both GarageBand and AU Lab.

Comment: AU Lab is now available through http://www.apple.com/itunes/mastered-for-itunes/

Answer (score 1):

[Soundflower](http://cycling74.com/products/soundflower/) is free and can capture your audio and send it through another application such as iTunes, which has an equalizer.

Comment: Intriguing. iTunes can “stream” from Soundflower? How?

Comment: Ah, yes - I don't know that iTunes can.  Try http://audacity.sourceforge.net/ instead.  Or Garage Band, as Lri suggests.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to do this with Audacity either. You can hear the input from Soundflower by selecting *Transport - Software Playthru (on / off)* and recording, but I didn't find a way to apply any effects in real time.

Answer (score 1):

Another viable solution is to use [Airfoil](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/), which can capture system audio and play it back locally (with a ~3-sec delay), and has an Effects menu which has a multi-band equalizer. (It’s not free but it’s a useful bit of software I already owned!)

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Audio Hijack](https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/). It can take system audio, apply filters to it (like noise removal, or high-pitch removal), and then reroute it back to the output speakers.