# Boost output volume past the maximum on OS X

Tags: macos, audio, osx-lion

The max volume on my iMac is way too low. I can barely hear videos in some online videos for example.

I know the volume can go louder though — depending on the audio source the iMac can be very loud.

So how can I increase the sound volume?

Comment: What app do you use for these videos?

Comment: flash and iTunes are the other main problems.

Comment: I'd like to be able to boost the volume for any app though.

Comment: vlc included...

Comment: Each od these apps has a volume control - have you got those at the max?

Comment: yes of course..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mac App Store - Boom](http://itunes.apple.com/app/id415312377) ($8.99):

[image]

---

You could modify the instructions at [osx - OS X: Filter system audio-out to remove high-pitched noise? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/321634/os-x-filter-system-audio-out-to-remove-high-pitched-noise). That's too complicated to be used as a permanent solution though.

---

iTunes has an option to normalize the playback volume: *Preferences → Playback → Sound Check*. As does VLC: *Preferences → Audio → Volume Normalizer*.