# OSX: app, script, or library for configuring bluetooth audio in unusual ways

Tags: macos, audio, bluetooth

What are some ways of configuring an OSX box to use wideband bluetooth audio from a bluetooth headset for mono input at the same time as using the headset for mono output of system audio, and how would I do this with more than one paired bluetooth headset at a time?

Answer (score 0):

You might use [Soundflower](http://cycling74.com/soundflower-landing-page/) to convert the input to mono. See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/321634/os-x-filter-system-audio-out-to-remove-high-pitched-noise/321791#321791). You might also need to create an aggregate device in Audio MIDI Setup.

The Accessibility (or Universal Access) preference pane has an option to convert audio output to mono.